Issues with combining logic of two eventlisterners
I am new to this, but i am trying to create a tweet list from a form. And here there are two eventlisteners at play. One that listens to submit, whereby the tweet is appended to a list. The other one listens to keydown, and track number of characters in the input field.
I want the keydown listener to reset upon submission, that is - I want the wordcount to show 0 again after I submit my tweet. Any advice?


const form = document.querySelector("#formContainer");
const input = document.querySelector("#input");
const output = document.querySelector("#output");
let charCount = input.value.length;

let newP = document.createElement("p");
let wordCount = document.querySelector("#wordCount");

input.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
  newP.innerText = charCount += 1;
  wordCount.append(newP);
});

form.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const thoughts = input.value;
  const list = document.createElement("li");
  list.innerText = thoughts;
  output.appendChild(list);
  input.value = "";
});
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Annoying Diary</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Diary</h1>
    <div><span>word count:</span> <span id="wordCount"></span></div>
    <form action="" id="formContainer">
      <input type="text" id="input" />
      <button>Post opinion!</button>
    </form>

    <h2>My thoughts!</h2>
    <ul id="output"></ul>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




Why can't you  just add append text with 0 to the wordcount once the steps of submit are completed
